# Change form position at runtime changing screen number

Tags: c#

I'm trying to change Form position to center after changing from a primary screen on a secondary screen

```
private void Form2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {

             ff = !ff;
             if(ff)
                 showOnScreen(1,this);
             else
                 showOnScreen(0,this); 
        }
    }



void showOnScreen(int screenNumber,Form frm)
    {
        Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;

        if (screenNumber >= 0 && screenNumber < screens.Length)
        {

            Location = screens[screenNumber].WorkingArea.Location;
            this.Location = new Point((screens[screenNumber].Bounds.Size.Width / 2) - (this.Size.Width / 2), (screens[screenNumber].Bounds.Size.Height / 2) - (this.Size.Height / 2));


        }
    }
```

The form is moved in center of screen but only in my primary screen

Comment: If the form is already on the screen, you will have to measure things yourself and change the Location property.

Comment: add the screen location to it https://stackoverflow.com/a/18496302/1383168

Comment: What I meant was, you should have edited your answer to include the link to where the ReallyCenterToScreen function came from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `StartPosition` manual of form to set start position value in `Location` Property.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
}
```

Also Take [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171764/how-to-position-the-opening-form-at-specific-location-in-c-sharp-windows-forms) From Here and also check my Another [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363374/showing-a-windows-form-on-a-secondary-monitor)

**Now 
Try to setting WindowStartUpLocation parameter as "manual" inside your showOnScreen method.**

Comment: sorry question has changed

Comment: let me check now