# Form with two panels to arrange location and size- C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# form application that contains two panels. One panel (panel1) contains a data grid view and the other panel  (panel2)contains some buttons and date time picker extra. What I am trying is panel1 should cover 80% of screen size and should be on the left side of the screen and  panel2 should cover 20% of the screen size and should be on the right side of the screen. Through anchor property, I managed to set the left and the right location. How to set the size? any leads? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to position the opening form at specific location in C# Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171764/how-to-position-the-opening-form-at-specific-location-in-c-sharp-windows-forms)

Comment: @SelimYıldız that is about location. not about size.

Comment: You should place a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=netframework-4.8) on your form and put the panels inside that, then you can specify the % each row/column should occupy. In your case, it will have only one row and two columns.